# How can I change label text from another viewController/Class?

Tags: swift, class, uiviewcontroller, label

I have a label that shows the amount of gold in ViewController1. If the user makes a purchase in the in-game-store in ViewController2, how can I update the labels text in ViewController1?

Basically, how can i change the label text from anoter viewController?
Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

In vc2 create closure something like this

`var actionBuy:(()->())?`

when action tapped use this `actionBuy?()`

it called in vc1

`vc2.actionBuy = {
  label.text = "action is done"
}`.

good luck